# Tesseract couldn\t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract

Tags: python, python-3.x, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have followed many tutorials and read many questions but still getting the error

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file \\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\eng.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'eng\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')
```

[image: environment variables]

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract as tess
import cv2
import os

tess.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
img = Image.open('5.jpg')
text = tess.image_to_string(img)

print(text)
```

Comment: error shows you path which it can't load - so check if you have it. On Linux I had some languages install separatelly.

Comment: Did you get past it? If yes, how so?

Comment: unfortunately no